# History of doubly periodic functions

Tags: elliptic-functions, modular-forms

I am curious about the origin and history of the doubly periodic function.  I was looking for the Eisenstein series, and the Eisenstein series is one of the representative examples of a doubly periodic function.  So I became curious about the origin and history of this doubly periodic function.

Comment: I took the liberty of improving your tags to match what I think you really want ... a little later, I will respond, if no one else does...

Comment: The article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function gives a brief summary answer. The double periodicity was a surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubly periodic functions first appeared as inverses of elliptic integrals that were originally motivated by computing the arc length of the lemniscate, but later found uses in astronomy (elliptic orbits), mechanics (non-linearized pendulum), etc. Good sources on this part of history are [Gray, The Real and the Complex](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-23715-2), and shorter [Mossiaguine, A Brief History of Elliptic Functions](https://kurser.math.su.se/pluginfile.php/16103/mod_folder/content/0/2019/2019_K4_report.pdf).

Elliptic integrals were studied by Fagnano, Euler and Legendre in the 18th century, but without any of them noticing that the inverse functions were doubly periodic. According to Gray, Gauss discovered that when he inverted the lemniscate integral in 1797, and then for general integrals in 1800.

> "*Gauss remarked in May 1800 (Diary entry nr. 108) that the new elliptic functions
> are doubly periodic and have zeros and poles and can be expanded as quotients of
> power series. His approach was two-fold: in one direction he inverted an elliptic
> integral depending on a parameter $k$; in the other he developed doubly periodic
> functions directly as quotients of entire functions. This raised the question of whether the two approaches define exactly the same objects. It was easy enough for Gauss to mimic the arguments for the lemniscatic integral in the general case, and conclude that the general elliptic function can be represented as a quotient. It proved much harder to show that every doubly periodic function defined as a quotient arises as the inverse of a suitable elliptic integral.*"

Alas, Gauss's researches were confined to his diaries, and so public appearance of doubly periodic functions had to await the work of Abel and Jacobi. Jacobi later opined why they were not discovered sooner:

> "*The fear that the mathematician most chiefly concerned with the determination of numerical values had of the imaginary, was the reason that Legendre was prevented from taking the most important step in modern analysis, the introduction of doubly periodic functions.*"

Abel published his first major paper on the subject, [*Recherches sur les fonctions elliptiques*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160913235716/http://www.abelprize.no/nedlastning/verker/oeuvres_1881_del1/oeuvres_completes_de_abel_nouv_ed_1_kap16_opt.pdf), in early 1827, motivated, in part, by a generalization of the circle division problem from Gauss’s *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* to the lemniscate. It was the first published work on doubly periodic functions, second part of it came out in 1828. Jacobi came to inverting elliptic integrals from a different angle, by considering transformations of elliptic integrals into each other by a rational change of the variables, he published at the end of 1827. Whether he did it before or after reading Abel's paper is a matter of dispute (he claimed the former).

The subsequent Abel-Jacobi rivalry turned out to be very fruitful for the subject and culminated in Jacobi's "*book that was to become the definitive account of the theory of elliptic functions for at least a generation*", *Fundamenta Nova Theoriae Functionum Ellipticarum* (1829). Abel tragically passed away the same year. Weierstrass got hold of Jacobi's book in 1836, and became the only student in Gudermann's class on them in 1839-40. But his own work on them started only in 1860-s, and built on Eisenstein's representation of them by double series. Eisenstein was drawn to the subject by Gauss, whom he admired (the feeling was mutual), in 1840-s. His main discoveries date to 1846-47, and he too got embroiled in priority disputes with Jacobi.

Comment: Yes, very good, thank you for writing this out. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Thanks to you, I was able to learn more about history.

Comment: With apologies for typo nit-picking: The name should be [Gudermann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoph_Gudermann).